# package xskak: problem with a line break in the notations

Tags: multicol, xskak

I have a problem with the combination of the packages `xskak` and `multicols`. Please look at the 7th move: `LaTeX` does not write the number of the move (7) and the move itself (O-O) in the same line. That is annoying. Does anybody of you have an idea how to fix this? Thanks for your help!

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{xskak} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{german}
\usepackage{multicol}

\parindent0em

\newcommand{\cchessboard}{\centerline{\chessboard}}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}

\large
\newchessgame
\mainline{1. e4 e6 2. d4 d5 3. exd5 exd5 4. Bd3 c5!}

\cchessboard
\mainline{5. dxc5 Bxc5 6. Nf3 Nf6 7.O-O O-O 8. c3 Nc6}

\cchessboard
\mainline{9. Bg5 h6!}

\cchessboard

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spaces and chars like dots or lines between the various part of the notation of a move are choosen by the style and can be adapted, see the documentation. You could e.g. use the UF-style which has only a small space in this place, or redefine the default styleB. You will perhaps want to redefine the castling hyphen too as it is a break point in the default configuration. Be aware that less breaking points means more white space and underfull lines.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multicol}
\parindent0em

\newcommand{\cchessboard}{\centerline{\chessboard}}

%\xskakset{style=UF}

\xskaknewstyleitem[%
 whiteopen=~, %instead of \space
 blackopen=\ldots,
 afterwhite=\space,
 afterblack=\space]{styleB}


\renewcommand\castlinghyphen{\mbox{-}}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}

\large
\newchessgame
\mainline{1. e4 e6 2. d4 d5 3. exd5 exd5 4. Bd3 c5!}

\cchessboard
\mainline{5. dxc5 Bxc5 6. Nf3 Nf6 7.O-O O-O 8. c3 Nc6}

\cchessboard
\mainline{9. Bg5 h6!}

\cchessboard

\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

[image]